# How to best implement dynamic dbt datasets

Tags: dbt

I'm cleaning up a dbt + BigQuery environment and trying to implement a staging environment that pulls from a staging dataset. Problem is that the current `.yml` files with source information all explicitly point to a production dataset.

One option that I am considering is a `source` wrapper function that will serve as an adapter and inject the proper dataset depending on some passed CLI `var` or profile target (which is different for the staging vs prod environments).

However, I'm fairly new to dbt so unsure if this is the best way to go about this. Would appreciate any insight you kind folks have :)

EDIT: I'm realizing that a `source` wrapper is not the way to go as it would mess with the generated DAG

Answer (score 2):

You can supply the name of the schema for a source in a [variable](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/var) or [environment variable](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/env_var), and set that variable at runtime.

In your `sources.yml`:

```yaml
version: 2

sources:
  - name: jaffle_shop
    schema: "{{ var('source_jaffle_shop_schema) }}"
    tables:
      - name: orders
```

In your `dbt_project.yml`:

```yaml
vars:
  - source_jaffle_shop_schema: MY_DEFAULT_SCHEMA
```

And then to override at runtime:

```bash
dbt run --vars "{source_jaffle_shop_schema: my_other_schema}"
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `var` in a `sources.yml` file. All the examples in the dbt docs involve using using `var` to inject into jinja templates. Moreover, when I do this, the full `var("table_name")` shows up in the compiled SQL files

Comment: @RubenFlam-Shepherd sorry, I forgot the curlies around `var` in my answer. I've updated it, and it should work for you now. You absolutely can use some jinja in your `yml` files, see https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/env_var